# Backpropagation NN - is it trained?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I am working on a simple Back propagation Neural Network that is predicting next value of a sensor reading. It took me a while to train it based on the last year data and now i have the results.

There are several inputs into my NN like temperature, humidity, day, month, hour.

The answer i want from the NN is: What is the next hour value for the sensor reading?

Let's say that at 13:00 reading is 50
What will be the sensor reading at 14:00 ?

Here are the outputs per hour:

**YELLOW**: Predicted

**GREEN** : Sensor reading

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I think i could use it as an eventual trend for the next hour, still i see some errors there.

Looking at the results above, how do you tell if

- this network is performing well / overfitted / under-fitted ?
- it suits at all

Here are the stats of the training:

> 1000000 epochs
>
> 3700 training set
>
> 3700 validation set
>
> Validation Error: 0.000376
>
> Training Error: 0.000214

Comment: Why would you expect your predictions to have no error?

Comment: I expect them to have a slight error, but i just want to confirm by the look at the output of the NN - if you spot anything that requires attention.

Comment: Only you can decide if the model is suitable for your needs. To me, it looks like the model is just predicting the time-series, but offset by 1 time unit -- the naive 1-step prediction.

Comment: @Sycorax, that's exactly what it was trained for, to predict next time series value (next hour value). What does the naive 1-step prediction mean ?

Comment: A great predictor of Google’s stock price tomorrow is its price today. I’m suggesting that your model is more-or-less outputting today’s measurement as its prediction. Try taking first differences and predicting the change relative to today.